# Backslashes in SQL query when concatenating fields from sequelize response

Tags: angular

I try to concatenate attribute field from sequelize response but it took backslash for some conditions like where ..

It gives following query :

```sql
SELECT `test`.`concat(\'https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/\', test)` AS `test.test`
FROM `test`
WHERE `test`.`status` = 1
  AND `test`.`id` = \'10\'
```

so it shows unknown column like:

```
Unknown column \'test.concat(\'https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/\', test)\' in \'field list\''
```

This is my select query api:

```typescript
app.put('/listmyorder/(:id1)/(:id2)',async(req,res)=>{

  await models.test1.findAll({
    where:{dev:req.params.id1,st:req.params.id2},
    attributes: ['id','date'],
    include:[
      {model: models.test,attributes: ['id',["concat('https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/', test)" , 'test']]}
    ]
  }).then(result=>{
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
      Code:"1",
      Message:"List",
      Data:result
    });
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      Code:"0",
      Message:"Something went wrong"
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you show the query you were expecting? So we can compare and have a better idea of what went wrong

Comment: if i concat the image like include:[
      {model: models.test,attributes: ['id',["concat('https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/', test)" , 'test']]}
    ] ----------------------------------------- in sequelize it shows error Unknown column \'test.concat(\'https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/\', test)\' in \'field list\''

Comment: i need query without front slash

Comment: You mean you need `concat('https://...', test)` without quotes? Either way it seems weird to have an **SQL column** named like an URL. Do you really have a column named this way?

Comment: yes rafalon i need first one

Comment: Did you actually read my questions? I'd like to help you, but keep in mind that people here can only see what you show. We are not going to hack your computer in order to help you, and we can't read your mind. Do you **really** have an SQL column which looks like `https://...`? Because you *seem* to be willing to run `SELECT test.https://[...] FROM test`